# Subgroups of a semidirect product with a cyclic group of order $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

> Let $G$ be a finite group. Is it true that every subgroup of $G\rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $H$ or $H\rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, where $H\subset G$ is a subgroup?

It is known that, in general, the structure of subgroups of a semidirect product is somewhat tricky. What can we say in this simple case?

Comment: some useful info in Arturo's answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5153/what-are-the-subgroups-of-a-semidirect-product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take the semidirect (in fact, just direct) product $\;\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2\;$ , which is the Klein group (the non-cyclic group of order four). Then, the subgroup $\;K:=\langle\,(1,1)\,\rangle\;$ is neither $\;K\le\Bbb Z_2\;$ nor $\;K\rtimes\Bbb Z_2\;$

Comment: I thought of the same example, but I assume that the OP meant "isomorphic" when he wrote "is of the form". But still +1

Comment: @M.U. Perhaps that'swhat he meant, yet there've been many questions here along the years about the general form of subgroups of (semi)direct products (and not what they're isomorphic to),  so I guess this is just one more of them.

Comment: The answer is no even if you "is of the form" means isomorphic to. The dihedral group of order $8$ is a semidirect product of $C_2 \times C_2$ with $C_2$, but it has a cyclic subgroup of order $4$.